# Erro ao instalar chatterbot com pip

Tags: python

Quando vou instalar o chatterbot aparece todos esses erros ,ja tentei algumas coisas e foi mas o chatterbot e o pyaudio tbm nao foi

````
Collecting chatterbot
  Using cached ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting pymongo<4.0,>=3.3
  Using cached pymongo-3.10.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (349 kB)
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
  Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9m_qm9na\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (117 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-49.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (789 kB)
  Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
    Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached Cython-0.29.20-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (1.6 MB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached cymem-2.0.3.tar.gz (51 kB)
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached murmurhash-1.0.2.tar.gz (35 kB)
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Nicholas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e1zqxybg\\thinc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Nicholas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e1zqxybg\\thinc\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-1qph92p5'
           cwd: C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1zqxybg\thinc\
      Complete output (97 lines):
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\tools\cythonize.py", line
59, in process_pyx
          from Cython.Compiler.Version import version as cython_version
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
  
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\tools\cythonize.py", line
235, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\tools\cythonize.py", line
231, in main
          find_process_files(root_dir)
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\tools\cythonize.py", line
222, in find_process_files
          process(root_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\tools\cythonize.py", line
188, in process
          processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\tools\cythonize.py", line
64, in process_pyx
          raise OSError('Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module')
      OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module
      Running from numpy source directory.
      C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\setup.py:460: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
          yield saved
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
          yield
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
          _execfile(setup_script, ns)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
          exec(code, globals, locals)
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\setup.py", line 489, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\setup.py", line 469, in setup_package
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\setup.py", line 274, in generate_cython
      RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
  
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1zqxybg\thinc\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1zqxybg\thinc\setup.py", line 201, in setup_package
          setup(
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
          dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
          resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
          dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
          return self.obtain(req, installer)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
          return installer(requirement)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
          return cmd.easy_install(req)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
          return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
          dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
          return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
          self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
          run_setup(setup_script, args)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
          raise
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
          self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
          yield
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
          self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
          saved_exc.resume()
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
          six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
          raise value.with_traceback(tb)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
          yield saved
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
          yield
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
          _execfile(setup_script, ns)
        File "c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
          exec(code, globals, locals)
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\setup.py", line 489, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\setup.py", line 469, in setup_package
        File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-8ci724xl\numpy-1.19.0\setup.py", line 274, in generate_cython
      RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
      Cythonizing sources
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\nicholas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9m_qm9na\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output. ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta instalar essa versão: `pip install chatterbot==1.0.4`

**Fonte:**
https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/1854#issuecomment-612394091

Comment: obrigado amigo parece que foi agora vou testar de criar um bot muitos valeus ai pra voce